# Handling CFSELECT

Tags: coldfusion

I'm totally unused to Cold Fusion, I'd like to know how to handle a multiple CFSELECT, in particular how to know how many rows I've selected and taking them one by one.
Actually I've managed to see all the rows togheter:

```
  <!--- page_a.cfm --->
  <cfform name="fooform" ........>
  <cfselect query="myquery" name="fornitori" multiple="yes"></cfselect>

  <!--- page_b.cfm --->
  <cfoutput>#form.fornitori#</cfoutput>
```

And, if it's not too much, I'd like to know why it's not correct to write:

```
<!--- page_b.cfm --->
<cfoutput>#fooform.fornitori#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a [multiple selection list](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0f76c-7fe0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0f76c-7fdc), the options you select will be submitted to page_b.cfm as a comma delimited list. This means you can use [list functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a42) to calculate the total items selected and [cfloop](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fe2.html) to iterate through the selections individually. Note, when using "multiple" select lists, if you select nothing the form field will not exist.

```
    <cfparam name="form.fornitori" default="">
    <cfoutput>
      Total Items Selected = <cfoutput>#listLen(form.fornitori)#</cfoutput>
      Individual Selections:<br>
      <cfloop list="#form.fornitori#" index="theSelection">
          #theSelection#<br>
      </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
```

> why it's not correct to write ..

Because `FORM` refers to a special system structure, not the name of your html form (ie fooform). `FORM` contains any form fields submitted via method=POST.

Answer (score 0):

```
#myquery.recordcount#
```

btw, use `cfdump` to display anything. you see some really interesting stuff (I'm not sure whether recordcount is in there though)

---

getting to the elements:

```
<cfoutput query="queryname">#title#<br />#content#</cfoutput>
```

inside the cfoutput you have access to the variables of an element.

[coldfusion 9 help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/index.html)

Comment: But.. how can I fetch the elements?

Comment: Maybe I've explained myself: I have a query that fills a select with multiple selection enabled. When I submit the form to the page b I'd like to fetch one by one the various lines selected by the user.

Comment: ah ok..so you don't want to iterate through a query, but rather through some random data.. it is best to `cfdump` all the data and see how they look like.. then you can iterate through the data with `cfloop`